# How to control constant spaces in article first page

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xparse}%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \null
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{12pc}%\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@presentaddress}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}


\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
  \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
    \raggedright  #1\VetriKVMacroEmail%
    }}

\def\@presentaddress{}
\def\presentaddress#1{%
     \gdef\@presentaddress{\textbf{\textit{$\dagger$presentaddress:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\let\@email\@empty
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\protected@edef\@email{#1}}

\let\@link\@empty
\newcommand{\link}[1]{\protected@edef\@link{\href{#1}{\author}}}



\define@key{authorinfo}{aff}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroAff{#1}%
}%


\define@key{authorinfo}{coraddress}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroCorAddress{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{email}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroEmail{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{link}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroLink{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{presentaddress}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress{#1}%
}%


\let\OriginalAuthor\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+O{}+m}{%
\setkeys{authorinfo}{#1}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroAff}{%
  \OriginalAuthor[\VetriKVMacroAff]{#2}%
}{%
  \OriginalAuthor{#2}% 
}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroCorAddress}{%
  \correspondence{\VetriKVMacroCorAddress}%
}{%
}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress}{%
  \presentaddress{\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress}%
}{%
}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroEmail}{%
  \email{\VetriKVMacroEmail}%
}{%
}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroLink}{%
  \link{\VetriKVMacroLink}%
}{%
}%
\undef\VetriKVMacroAff%
}% End of RenewDocumentCommand.


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[aff={1},link={https://www.google.co.in},coraddress={Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology},email={keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk},]{Junli Liu}
\author[aff={2},presentaddress=James Rowe continued from this author address\newline e-mail: James@durham.ac.uk]{James Rowe}
\author[aff={2}]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I try to maintain the constant space in opening page. But i don't know how to code the `\maketitle`. My need is constant space is maintain the Edited, reviewed and correspondence. Some cases reviewed by details is not given. This cases the space  increased constant 6pt changed to 12pt

My `.tex` file coding below mentioned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@editor\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@reviewer\par}
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@metanote}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@abstract\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@keywords\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@firstpara\par}
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}

\def\@editor{}
\def\editor#1{%
     \gdef\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}

\newcommand\reviewerhead{\raggedright \textbf{Reviewed by:}\newline}

\def\@reviewer{}
\def\reviewer#1{%
     \gdef\@reviewer{\reviewerhead #1}}

\def\@metanote{}
\def\metanote#1{%
     \gdef\@metanote{\raggedright  #1}}

\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@abstract{}
\def\abstract#1{%
     \gdef\@abstract{\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\selectfont #1}}

\def\@keywords{}
\def\keywords#1{%
     \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}}

\def\@firstpara{}
\def\firstpara#1{%
     \gdef\@firstpara{ #1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\editor{Wagner L. Ara\'{u}jo, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{%\protect\includegraphics{Saravana.jpg}\newline
Keith Lindsey is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology in the School of Biological and Biomedical Science sat Durham University, UK. His research interests are in understanding how genes and signaling systems regulate the development of plants. Most of his work is with the model experimental organism Arabidopsis thaliana.\newline \href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}
\abstract{Plants are sessile organisms and therefore they must adapt their growth and architecture to a changing environment.}
\metanote{$\dagger$Joint corresponding authors}
\keywords{root development, POLARIS peptide, hormonal crosstalk, osmotic stress, kinetic modelin}
\firstpara{\section*{Introduction}
Hormone signaling systems coordinate plant growth and development through a range of com- plex interactions. The activities of hormones such as auxin, ethylene, cytokinin, abscisic acid, gibberellin, and brassinosteroids depend on cellular context and exhibit either synergistic or antagonistic interactions. Additionally, auxin is directionally transported through plant tissues, providing positional and vectorial information during development (Vanneste and Friml, 2009).\hfilneg}
\maketitle



\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression of speciÞc genes.

\end{document}
```

My output and requirement below mentioned[image]

Comment: It seems to me that it already does what you want. `\vskip 6pt` is what has to be changed if you want a different spacing.

Comment: In such cases Reviewed by details is not given. In this case Edited by and correspondence in between space will be taken 12pt. But my need is constant 6pt. How to implement the logic if the reviewed by content is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all the lines

```
\vskip 6pt%
```

with

```
\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\unskip\fi\vskip 6pt%
```

In this way, if the last skip was greater than `0pt`, it is removed and you always get `6pt` of vertical skip.

MWE (with `\reviewer` commented)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@editor\par}%
\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\unskip\fi\vskip 6pt%
{\@reviewer\par}
\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\unskip\fi\vskip 6pt%
{\@correspondence\par}%
\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\unskip\fi\vskip 6pt%
{\@metanote}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@abstract\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@keywords\par}
    \vskip 1em%
    {\@firstpara\par}
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}

\def\@editor{}
\def\editor#1{%
     \gdef\@editor{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\newline #1}}

\newcommand\reviewerhead{\raggedright \textbf{Reviewed by:}\newline}

\def\@reviewer{}
\def\reviewer#1{%
     \gdef\@reviewer{\reviewerhead #1}}

\def\@metanote{}
\def\metanote#1{%
     \gdef\@metanote{\raggedright  #1}}

\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@abstract{}
\def\abstract#1{%
     \gdef\@abstract{\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\selectfont #1}}

\def\@keywords{}
\def\keywords#1{%
     \gdef\@keywords{\textbf{Keywords:} #1}}

\def\@firstpara{}
\def\firstpara#1{%
     \gdef\@firstpara{ #1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[1]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\editor{Wagner L. Ara\'{u}jo, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
%\reviewer{Jedrzej Jakub Szymanski, Max Planck Institute of Molecular Plant Physiology, Germany }
%\reviewer{Dimas Mendes Ribeiro, Universidade Federal de Vi\c{c}osa, Brazil}
\correspondence{%\protect\includegraphics{Saravana.jpg}\newline
Keith Lindsey is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology in the School of Biological and Biomedical Science sat Durham University, UK. His research interests are in understanding how genes and signaling systems regulate the development of plants. Most of his work is with the model experimental organism Arabidopsis thaliana.\newline \href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}
\abstract{Plants are sessile organisms and therefore they must adapt their growth and architecture to a changing environment.}
\metanote{$\dagger$Joint corresponding authors}
\keywords{root development, POLARIS peptide, hormonal crosstalk, osmotic stress, kinetic modelin}
\firstpara{\section*{Introduction}
Hormone signaling systems coordinate plant growth and development through a range of com- plex interactions. The activities of hormones such as auxin, ethylene, cytokinin, abscisic acid, gibberellin, and brassinosteroids depend on cellular context and exhibit either synergistic or antagonistic interactions. Additionally, auxin is directionally transported through plant tissues, providing positional and vectorial information during development (Vanneste and Friml, 2009).\hfilneg}
\maketitle



\noindent Patterning in Arabidopsis root development is coordinated via a localized auxin concentration maximum in the root tip (Sabatini et al., 1999), requiring the regulated expression of speciÞc genes.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I got the solution

Comment: @Vetri Happy about that.